How to compare XRD data from literature?
I'm a grad student. Trying to do a literature review this summer. My advisor is telling me to gather XRD data of my samples for my research, and I have. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to compare it/use it with the data from the literature. I'm just looking at aluminum alloys and different ways they are deposited onto a substrate (arc spraying, flame spray, cold gas spray, etc...)
How do I use data from the literature in a scientific way beyond "Oh look this technique gives us this crystal structure, that's nice."? I'm lost, and don't really want to ask my advisor this yet, I'm tired of looking like I know nothing in front of him. Can I even compare XRD data to literature results if they use a different machine? Not to mention different sources/grating spacings.

Step one, talk to whomever operates the XRD system about how to compare spectra. Two, understand what kind of information you can get from XRD and what that instrument measures. But, yes, you can compare and gets lots of information about what the film you have deposited (that is not single crystal) is doing. Things like grain size, texture, etc...
